# jQuery issue with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two anchor links One is `Like` and Second is `Favorite` Now I am trying get alert when user click to specific option.

If user click to `Like` option `alert('Like Clicked');`

or

If user click to `Favorite` option `alert('Favorite Clicked');`

but something is wrong and getting multiple alerts with Like and Favorite.

Whats wrong with my code I can't understated.

**MY JS WORK:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.ovrly a').click( function () {
        var getImageID = $(this).attr("id"); //class name with id

        if($(".like").children("."+getImageID)) {
            alert('Like Clicked');  
        }

        if($(".fav").children("."+getImageID)) {
            alert('Favourite Clicked'); 
        }
    });
});
```

**MY HTML WORK:**

```
<div class="ovrly">
    <span class="like">
        <a class="like_32" id="like_32" href="javascript:void(0);">Like</a>
        <p class="likeCount_32">
            15
        </p> 
    </span>

    <span class="fav">
        <a class="favourite_32" id="favourite_32" href="javascript:void(0);">Favourite</a>
        <p class="favouriteCount_32">
            09
        </p> 
    </span>
</div>
```

My Sample [JS FIDDLE](http://goo.gl/jzTM87)

**My Sample Code With Ajax Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // like and favourite ajax script
    $(function () {
        $('.load_more_ctnt .ovrly a').live("click", function () {
            var getImageID = $(this).attr("id"); //class name with id
            var getID = getImageID.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ""); //only id
            var getOptionName = getImageID.replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g, ""); //only id
            //alert(getImageID);

            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {

                if($(".like").children("."+getImageID).length > 0) {
                    alert('Like Clicked');  
                }

                if($(".fav").children("."+getImageID).length > 0) {
                    alert('Favourite Clicked'); 
                }

            }).ajaxStop(function() {


               if($(".like").children("."+getImageID).length > 0) {
                    alert('Like Clicked');  
               }

               if($(".fav").children("."+getImageID).length > 0) {
                    alert('Favourite Clicked'); 
               }

            });

            if (getImageID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo URL; ?>home/passImageID",
                    data: "getImageID=" + getImageID,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $("#" + getImageID).removeAttr("id");

                        if(html == 'like'){
                            $("." + getImageID).addClass( "iplike" );
                            var incrementBy1 = $(".likeCount_" + getID).text();
                            var tempLikeNewValue = +incrementBy1+1;
                            $(".likeCount_" + getID).text("");
                            $(".likeCount_" + getID).text(tempLikeNewValue);

                        }else{

                            $("." + getImageID).addClass( "ipfav" );
                            var incrementBy1 = $(".favouriteCount_" + getID).text();
                            var tempFavNewValue = +incrementBy1+1;
                            $(".favouriteCount_" + getID).text("");
                            $(".favouriteCount_" + getID).text(tempFavNewValue);

                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                 //$(".more_tab").html('The End');
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Add length to check if elements exists

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [**.is()**](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.

*Code*

```
$('.ovrly a').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(".like_32")) {
        alert('Like Clicked');
    }

    if ($(this).is(".favourite_32")) {
        alert('Favorite Clicked');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B24AX/3/)

Comment: To expand to the OP on why what he did didn't work, it's because the check was checking if the children exist at all, and not if they're the ones clicked

Answer (score 1):

reference **[hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)**

```
$('.ovrly').on('click','a',function () {

if ($(this).hasClass("like_32")) {
        alert('Like Clicked');
    }

    if ($(this).hasClass("favourite_32")) {
        alert('Favorite Clicked');
    }

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B24AX/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

`$(".like").children("."+getImageID)` the code provide you children element selector object, for the exist check, you can use langth.

```
if($(".like").children("."+getImageID).length > 0) {
            alert('Like Clicked');  
        }
```

Comment: Hi your code is working but when I put that inside this `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {   }).ajaxStop(function() {     });` not working.

Comment: @user3113858 , this will work on all other ajax call, you should add code inside `beforeSend` and `complete` ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that both conditions are always true!

```
$(".like").children("." + getImageID)

$(".fav").children("." + getImageID)
```

You are not comparing anything. Both statements return true since both elements exists in your page.

Answer (score 0):

use length in jquery

```
if ($(".like").children("." + getImageID).length > 0) {
    alert('Like Clicked');
}

if ($(".fav").children("." + getImageID).length > 0) {
    alert('Favorite Clicked');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B24AX/4/)

Comment: Hey your code is working great but need your small help if possible. This code is not working in this ajaxStart and ajaxStop. Can you guide me. `$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
 
}).ajaxStop(function() {
   
});`

Comment: Thanks for supporting me:) I am adding in my question.

Comment: I have added in my question. plz check :)

Comment: Ok all right in ajax call alert not worked please use console.log instead of alert it works

Comment: Hey I am new with this kind of stuff. Can you explain me how. :(

Comment: Hey I have tried with this ~console.log('Like Clicked');~ but still getting wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another option...

```
$('#favourite_32').click(function () {

    alert('Favorite Clicked');

});
$('#like_32').click(function () {

    alert('Like Clicked');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

your approach is correct, but you have little bit diverted from basic concept.

`$(".like").children("."+getImageID)` and `$(".fav").children("."+getImageID)` both are returning object.

In case, when you click on like then

```
$(".like").children("."+getImageID) return a object of array that have element.
$(".feb").children("."+getImageID) return a object of array that are empty.
```

but in both case there is object of array and for a object of array if condition is always true.

try to execute on js console :

```
if([]){
  console.log("it will print that condition is true")
}
```

then you alwaye find:

```
it will print that condition is true
```

You would have use for correct working.

```
if($(".like").children("."+getImageID).length>0){

}
```

and

```
if($(".like").children("."+getImageID).length > 0){
}
```